# Error message in loglm1.data.frame

Tags: r, dataset, regression

I have a dataset TAB:

```
> TAB
  Group Type Freq
1  eng     1  513
2   ger    1  369
3  eng     2  625
4   ger    2  758
```

I want to run a simple stepwise log-linear regression:

```
library(MASS)

lg.TAB.0 <- loglm(~1, TAB)
lg.TAB.1 <- loglm(~Group, TAB)
lg.TAB.2 <- loglm(~Type, TAB)
lg.TAB.3 <- loglm(~Group+Type, TAB)
lg.TAB.4 <- loglm(~Group*Type, TAB)
anova(lg.TAB.0,lg.TAB.1,lg.TAB.2,lg.TAB.3,lg.TAB.4, test="Chisq")
```

However, I am getting this error message:

> ```
> > lg.TAB.0 <- loglm(~1, TAB)
> Error in loglm1.data.frame(formula, data, ..., .call = .call, .formula = 
> .formula) : formula specifies no response
> ```

Does anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: Try `loglm(~1, xtabs(Freq~Group+Type, TAB))`

Comment: it worked. but oddly I get χ2 = 0 and df = 0 when I run an `anova(lg.TAB.4, test = "Chisq")`. so, is there something wrong in how I specify the interaction Group*Type?..